# Nexus cleanup old releases for minor versions

Tags: regex, maven, nexus

I need to cleanup old releases for all minor versions.

I mean that I need to keep only last releases: 1.12.54, 1.13.23, 1.14.68

All previous releases for selected minor version must be deleted, to keep only 1.12.max, 1.13.max, 1.14.max and etc

Nexus offers to setup regexp pattern for Repository Targret in doc [Managing Repository Targets](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/repository-targets.html)
Configured "Repository Target" later can be used in Scheduled task to remove old releases.

Can anyone help with this pattern? Or may be you have more useful solution?

Comment: I dont think we can use regex here.. This involves comparisions and regex is only for pattern matching.

Comment: What is the input format that you are dealing with?

Comment: At the current time I added for sprint 1.15 Repository Target with pattern "/com/mycompany/app/1[.]15[.].*"  to cleanup releases.

Comment: But I don't like to create Repository Target every time for every Sprint (we work with agile scrum sprints and we have scheduled autorelease in Jenkins for aplications)

Is it possible to configure only one Repository Target to cleanup releases?

Comment: did you end up with a satifactory solution for this yet?, We have the same problem of having many (minor) releases (as well as snapshots) which need to be cleaned up, doing it with a shell script seems counter intuitive and error prone :(

Answer (score 0):

The "remove old releases" task isn't designed for your use case, it is designed to keep the last "n" most recent releases.

Your best bet would be to write a script to delete these directly from local storage, and then have the script call the REST API's outlined here:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/38605563-Can-I-directly-update-artifacts-in-Nexus-local-storage-on-disk-